# Indenting text with a new environment command

Tags: indentation

I intend to make a command that indents all text between `\begin{pinden}{3cm}` and `\end{pinden}{3cm}`.  But what happens is that the first text that appears is not indented, but the remaining are
indented properly.

```
%% lexi.sty

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter 

\newlength\pinden@len
\newenvironment{pinden}[1]{
  \setlength{\pinden@len}{\the\parindent}
  \setlength{\parindent}{#1}
}{
  \setlength{\parindent}{\pinden@len}
}

\makeatother
```

Hence

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[b5paper,body={13cm,18cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage[italian,french,spanish,icelandic,english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lexi}
  
\begin{document}

\newtoggle{show-language-orthography}
\toggletrue{show-language-orthography}

\iftoggle{show-language-orthography}{

   \begin{otherlanguage*}{icelandic}

      \newpage

      \section{Icelandic Orthography}
      \subsection{Icelandic Alphabet - Majuscule forms}

      \begin{pinden}{3cm}
         a á b d ð e é f g h i í j k l m n o ó
   
         p r s t u ú v x y ý þ æ ö

         p r s t u ú v x y ý þ æ ö
      \end{pinden}

   \end{otherlanguage*}

}{}

\end{document}
```

gives

```
a á b d ð e é f g h i í j k l m n o ó
       
             p r s t u ú v x y ý þ æ ö
    
             p r s t u ú v x y ý þ æ ö
```

Comment: Can you post a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)? If I make a simple document with `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\makeatletter` ... (your code) ... `\makeatother\begin{document}` ... (your example) ... `\end{document}` I do not get the result you report.

Comment: Yes, but quoting is a different environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to save and restore the value of `\parindent`, because any change you do in the `pinden` environment will be discarded as soon as `pinden` ends.
2. The first paragraph after a section title is not indented.
3. You're trying to reinvent the wheel.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[b5paper,body={13cm,18cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian,french,spanish,icelandic,english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{pinden}[1]{%
  \@afterindenttrue
  \setlength\parindent{#1}%
}{\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{icelandic}

\section{Icelandic Orthography}
\subsection{Icelandic Alphabet - Majuscule forms}

      \begin{pinden}{3cm}
         a á b d ð e é f g h i í j k l m n o ó

         p r s t u ú v x y ý þ æ ö

         p r s t u ú v x y ý þ æ ö
      \end{pinden}

\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What about point 3?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[b5paper,body={13cm,18cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian,french,spanish,es-noquoting,icelandic,english]{babel}

\newenvironment{pinden}[1]{%
  \list{}{%
    \leftmargin=#1\relax
    \rightmargin=0pt
    \topsep=0pt
    \partopsep=0pt
    \parsep=0pt
    \itemsep=0pt
  }\item\relax
}{\endlist}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{icelandic}

\section{Icelandic Orthography}
\subsection{Icelandic Alphabet - Majuscule forms}

      \begin{pinden}{3cm}
         a á b d ð e é f g h i í j k l m n o ó
   
         p r s t u ú v x y ý þ æ ö

         p r s t u ú v x y ý þ æ ö
      \end{pinden}

\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

It would be easier with the `quoting` package, say

```
\newenvironment{pinden}[1]{%
  \quoting[indentfirst=false,vskip=0pt,leftmargin=#1,rightmargin=0pt]%
}{\endquoting}
```

but, unfortunately, this is not compatible with `babel-spanish`.

Comment: Would that merit a bug report for `babel-spanish`?  Perhaps we have got to something here.

Comment: Why have you included an additional version that uses  `\list`  ?

Comment: @Randy Because it's a cleaner implementation and much easier to customize.